# Как реализовать подсчёт количества символов текстового файла?

Tags: php, laravel, файлы, php7

Необходимо сделать подсчёт количества символов в текстовом файле, а затем рассчитать примерное количество времени для прочтения текста. Всё это нужно сделать с поддержкой форматов PDF, DOC, DOCX, ODF и RTF. При этом файлы могут содержать картинки, таблицы, и ссылки.

На проекте используется Laravel 7. Рассматривал библиотеку https://github.com/NinoSkopac/PhpTikaWrapper, но она не устанавливается из-за конфликта зависимостей. Как проще всего реализовать задуманное?

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, конвертацию разных документов в текст лучше доверить специальным утилитам типа [Tika](http://tika.apache.org/1.24.1/gettingstarted.html). А в php передать уже результат, который записать в базу (или чем ваш ларавель занимается).

UPD:
Проглядел, что вы его и хотели, только зачем-то с обёрткой на php. Поставьте отдельно. А в php просто результат отправляйте в stdin команды или, если очень хочется из php вызывать, то через какой-нибудь passthru (только не во время обработки http-запроса :-)).